# Где взять базу слов для Русско-Английского словаря?

Tags: python

Пишу простой Англо-Русский словарь на Python 3. Пользователь вводит слово - выводит его аналог на английском (как же иначе). Так вот, просмотр перевода слова осуществляется через .txt файл где слова записаны(example):

```
дом
house
дом
цветок
flower
цветок
```

и так далее.

Чтобы словарь был хоть на что-либо способен нужно 2000+ слов. Может уже существует скрипт для заполнения файла таким образом, используя ресурсы какого-нибудь сайта?

*Я новичок, только начинаю постигать  ООП, поэтому написать этот скрипт сам не в состоянии, а вбивать 6000 слов вручную слишком затратно по времени.*

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PZGognsH6PMux5wVKTT8DaOjPEoFMvaF/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rgX9Ak7BqxhzD5rqjs-HsIxKq2uMBMgV/view?usp=sharing 2 словаря на 86000 слов в форматах txt и JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Погуглил `2000 слов на английском языке` и нашел [сайт](http://www.7english.ru/dictionary.php?id=2000&letter=all). Осмотрел его `HTML` содержимое и решил попарсить.

Главная проблема была в том, что у сайта структура данных очень неудобная – нет атрибутов-маячков (`class`, `id`), по которым удобно выцеплять данные, поэтому понадобилось изучить структуру и найти точные данные (например, наличие определенного атрибута), чтобы отделить нужные данные.

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/2c6306c575f58d5ee970c70a690a2ad46ba6c928/parse_en_ru_words/www.7english.ru_dictionary.php_id=2000_letter=all/main.py#L18)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rs = requests.get('http://www.7english.ru/dictionary.php?id=2000&letter=all')
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

en_ru_items = []

for tr in root.select('tr[onmouseover]'):
    td_list = [td.text.strip() for td in tr.select('td')]

    # Количество ячеек в таблице со словами -- 9
    if len(td_list) != 9 or not td_list[1] or not td_list[5]:
        continue

    en = td_list[1]

    # Русские слова могут быть перечислены через запятую 'ты, вы',
    # а нам достаточно одного слова
    # 'ты, вы' -> 'ты'
    ru = td_list[5].split(', ')[0]

    en_ru_items.append((en, ru))

print(len(en_ru_items), en_ru_items)
# 2000 [('a', 'неопределенный артикль'), ('abili... , ('zero', 'ноль')]
```

---

Думаю, вывести этот список в файл автор уже сам сможет

Comment: Да, пожалуй с этим я справлюсь, спасибо большое, очень помогли

Answer (score 4):

По этому запросу: `русский английский словарь txt -разговорник`, нашёлся "Англо-Русский Словарь" Мюллера 1995-го года, не форматирован, обычный текст **txt**, 120 тыс. строк, 10 МБ:

http://www.alleng.ru/d/engl/engl150.htm

Более продвинутый запрос `google translate download dictionary txt` дал более плодотворные результаты, по ссылке ниже куча словарей в формате **XML**. Первый попавшийся русско-английский содержит 1 млн 458 тыс строк и весит 107 МБ:

http://translateclient.com/download_dictionary/

К сожалению, компактного и простого для новичка `txt`/`csv` не нашёл, видимо, мало кому такие вещи требуются. Но если Вам действительно важна эта задача, то справитесь с парсингом одного из этих. Выбирайте и пользуйтесь на здоровье!

Comment: Я видел эти словари, до того как задать вопрос, конечно же, но запись в них произведена не в том виде, который мне требуется.