# Как найти оффлайн переводчик на python(или просто сам по себе)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек, перевод, google-translate

Почти все либы для переводов текста на питоне, имеют ограничения по отправляемым запросам, как я понял.

Хотелось бы найти такую либу которая всю библиотеку переводов принесёт с собой, если такая существует, уже устал гуглить(.

Качество перевода не так важно, переводить планирую с английского на русский по одному слову, но их будет отправляться очень очень много подряд.

В крайнем случае может кто знает офлайн переводчики для винды, которые поддерживают консольные команды?

Comment: Вопрос уже был. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425218/offline-language-translation-api

Comment: По одному слову давно уже никто не переводит, контекст очень важен. Поэтому и требуются современные продвинутые программы для перевода. А что хоть переводить то планируется?

Comment: Максимум что могу я посоветовать - это http://www.statmt.org/moses/index.php?n=Main.HomePage
Использовать его, перед этим только научить на базе данных :/

Но это долгий вариант, как бы не хотелось.

Comment: @CrazyElf Хотел написать банальную программку в обучающих целях, кидаешь в неё файл с субтитрами, а она тебе топ самых популярных слов в виде таблицы возвращает. Мне казалось будет будет круто если, помимо прочего, они сразу с переводами будут. Не думал что это такой проблемой окажется)

Comment: Ну, таких топовых слов думаю немного будет по сравнению со всем списком слов. А вот этот вопрос смотрели: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767440/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F

Comment: Вот ещё, кстати. Вроде работает, но не знаю, какие там ограничения https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5cab3ea044061700afead675/svoi-perevodchik-s-raznyh-iazykov-na-python-5f857a928e35355ad1852a60

Comment: В последней ссылке используют эту библиотеку вроде бы https://github.com/terryyin/translate-python

Comment: Спасибо что хотите помочь, но к сожалению либа из двух последних комментариев тоже имеет ограничения. "MYMEMORY WARNING: YOU USED ALL AVAILABLE FREE TRANSLATIONS FOR TODAY. NEXT AVAILABLE IN  10 HOURS 28 MINUTES 22 SECONDSVISIT HTTPS://MYMEMORY.TRANSLATED.NET/DOC/USAGELIMITS.PHP TO TRANSLATE MORE"

Comment: попробуй модуль vosk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://skeptric.com/python-offline-translation/index.html

Marian Machine Translation крутая штука, лучше чем Argos

может 2 года назад и не было этого, но на английском почти сразу нагуглил это

Comment: ну это не словарь а полноценный переводчик, там нейронка на пайторч, но ставится и используется просто